# PXSelect Not Always Querying Database

Tags: acumatica

I am running a PXSelect statement that is not always querying the database when the code is hit. If it is the first run, it will query the DB, but after that it just uses the results from the previous query (which is no good). Is there any way to force PXSelect to always query the database using the BQL to SQL translated code? If so, how would I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the data getting modified by a different application directly through the database? The out of the box behaviour is typically correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe PXSelectReadonly is what you are looking for. Use it in place of PXSelect.

Sometimes we find it necessary to clear the Query Cache which should also allow your PXSelect to work if needed. Example:

```
MyView.Cache.ClearQueryCache();
```

Comment: This is what I do as well to make sure the DB is queried.

Comment: That did it! I put both the ClearQueryCache() and the PXSelectReadonly and it worked. Do you have any tips on when to use PXSelect vs PXSelectReadonly?

Comment: I think it really depends on how the data is being updated outside of your graph. If you are using the graph as indented you should not need PXSelectReadOnly as the graph has the updated values. So to answer your question. it usually has to do with updating data in another graph or direct via SQL.